# ItemFileWriteStore: how to change the data?

Tags: dojo

I'd like to change the data in my dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore.

Currently I have...

```
var rawdataCacheItems = [{'cachereq':'14:52:03','name':'Test1','cacheID':'3','ver':'7'}];
var cacheInfo = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        data: {
            identifier: 'cacheID',
            label: 'cacheID',
            items: rawdataCacheItems
        }
    });
```

I'd like to make a XHR request to get a new JSON string of the data to render.

What I can't work out is how to change the data in the "items" held by ItemFileWriteStore.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Thanks
Jeff Porter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give +1 to Alex Cheng since he info lead me to the solution.

This is how I solved my problem..

My JSONExtractor class...

```
private String setupCacheTabData()
{
JSONArray jsonList = new JSONArray();

List<IDataDelivery> cacheDeliveryRecords = service.getCacheDeliveryRecords();

for (IDataDelivery cache : cacheDeliveryRecords)
{
  JSONObject jsonO = new JSONObject();
  try
  {
    jsonO.put("cacheID", cache.getCacheID());
    jsonO.put("cacheversion", cache.getVersion());
    jsonList.put(jsonO);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    log.error("Error decoding CACHE database row for JSON (WILL SKIP): CACH_ID=" + cache.getCacheID(), e);
  }
}

return jsonList.toString().replace("\"", "'");
```

}

My Javascrip code...

```
var cacheInfo;

var rawdataCacheInfo = <s:property value='%{cacheString}'/>;
cacheInfo = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        data: {
            identifier: 'cacheId',
            label: 'cacheId',
            items: rawdataCacheInfo
        }
    });

function do() {
    var xhrArgs = {

        url: "../secure/jsonServlet?class=JSONExtractor&startDate="+startDateValue+"&startTime="+startTimeValue,
        handleAs: "json",
        preventCache: true,
        load: function(data) {
            // remove items...
            var allData = cacheInfo._arrayOfAllItems;
            for (i=0;i<allData.length;i++) {
                if (allData[i] != null) {
                    cacheInfo.deleteItem(allData[i]);
                }
            }
            // save removal of items.
            ddInfo.save();
            // add new items
            for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                cacheInfo.newItem(data[i]);
            }

        },
        error: function(error) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use functions provided by [`dojo.data.api.Write`](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/data/api/Write) API to modify the items in a store.

For example, you can use `newItem` to create a new item in the store, use `deleteItem` to remove an item in the store and use `setValue` to update attributes of an existing item.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeff Porter

In your code you say " ***ddInfo.save();*** "

I don't see any variables instantiated with that name.

Did you mean '***cacheInfo.save()***' ?